# 4K camcorder question

Tags: camcorder

Nowadays I am using 1920 x 1080 for all my videos/projects using Sony PMW-100.

I would like to start making more detailed stuff in a year or two.

Specifically in the mid-late 2014 I have a plan to make a documentary film.

I would like to use similar small camcoder but wit hthe higher resolution 4096 × 2304.

Do you think that some camcoders capable of 4K recording without the need of external recording source would be in the stores in the mid 2014 and the price would be no more than 5000 EUR at that time?

Comment: Hi Derfder - asking the community to predict manufacturers timing and pricing models is offtopic here I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JVC was first out of the gate with an [affordable consumer 4K camera](http://nofilmschool.com/2012/01/wanted-3k-3k-red-scarlet-jvc-you/).
Sony is showing their first [4K "Handycam" prototype](http://www.engadget.com/2013/01/07/sonys-4k-handycam-and-hxr-ifr5-4k-interface-unit-prototypes-eye/) at Consumer Electronics Show in Las Vegas...

So, I think the answer is YES :)

Comment: Thanks, what about the storage part? E.g. Hobbit at 40fps 3 hours is 20TB of storage. (100mb a frame). And 20fps is twice less.

Comment: E.g. this guy from TimeScapes http://vimeo.com/36969764 says that a project in Adobe Premiere of 45 minutes is about 5TB.